# Why do some viewers/editors not properly open this SVG file?

Tags: inkscape, svg, transparency, libreoffice-draw, image-formats

Consider [this SVG file](https://app.box.com/s/lkkh2ydk336tgj7l8u738k4x3ptksssl) (box.com link; I can't upload it here.)

It has a "checked" or "marked-v" symbol, black on transparency. The weird thing is, some viewers show it properly, while others show it as completely empty, i.e. all-transparency. As far as editors go, both LibreOffice Draw and Inkscape show an empty canvas when loading it, while gimp shows the actual check-mark (it rasterizes it of course).

Is there really something wrong with the SVG, or is it the apps' fault? Regardless, can I alter the SVG so that it would be more likely to be read correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One key to understanding SVG files is to realize they aren't like other, common image file formats. They are a markup language more similar to HTML and XML. This is your SVG file's source:

```xml
<!-- This Source Code Form is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public
   - License, v. 2.0. If a copy of the MPL was not distributed with this
   - file, You can obtain one at http://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/. -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
    <path fill="context-fill" fill-opacity="context-fill-opacity" d="M6 14a1 1 0 0 1-.707-.293l-3-3a1 1 0 0 1 1.414-1.414l2.157 2.157 6.316-9.023a1 1 0 0 1 1.639 1.146l-7 10a1 1 0 0 1-.732.427A.863.863 0 0 1 6 14z"/>
</svg>
```

That `path` statement is your checkmark. The `d=`attribute is the instructions which define the shape of the checkmark. Think of it like a perfectly transparent (invisible) piece of glass. The glass exists... but you can't see it. You can feel it and its shape... but you have to do more to it to make it so you can see that shape.

What you don't have here is a stroke attribute. A stroke would define a line around the outside edge of the shape. We can define the stroke's width (how thick the line is), its color, and other properties. Having not done so... however... there is no line around our invisible glass shape... so it remains invisible.

We do have fill properties (`fill=` and `fill-opacity=`). Fill defines the color and content of the surface of your shape. **However, the fill properties are set to `context-fill` and `context-fill-opacity`. Context-fill is a non-standard feature.** It is likely to be supported by the newer version of major browsers (I personally tested it with the newest Edge, Firefox, and Chrome)... however, there is no guarantee it will be supported by image viewers and editors that are more likely to stay closer to the standards. Any application which doesn't support this feature is likely to just ignore it entirely.

And this is your problem. You have no stroke... and, in apps that don't support context-fill, you have no fill. This leaves you with that invisible pieces of glass. It's there... you just can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

When I loaded the file into Inkscape, it appeared empty, but Control-A selected "all of it." Using the stroke and fill feature of Inkscape, I left fill empty, and added stroke color.

[image: check marks]

The top image has a 0.265mm stroke width, while the bottom has a much smaller value.

Comment: But, again, why doesn't it appear to have a fully-black fill?

Comment: At the start, there was no stroke color and also no fill color. Once you've selected it, it's just a click in Inkscape to add the desired fill. I omitted that step for clarity.